# Find an equation to tangent line of $1+\ln(xy)=e^{x-y}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Find an equation to the tangent line to the graph of the function at the point $(1,1)$.

$$1+\ln(xy)=e^{x-y}$$

I know you are first supposed to find the first derivative and then plug in for $x$ (in this case $1$) to get the equation to the tangent line, but I am having trouble with just finding the 1st derivative to the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and you have an implicit function, so implicit differentiation is the way to go. Start with the given equation and apply $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides:

$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(1+\ln(xy)\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x-y}\right)\\
\frac{xy'+y}{xy} &=(1-y')e^{x-y},
\end{align}$

where I'm writing $y'$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. At this point, you can plug in your values ($x=1,y=1$), and solve for $y'$ to get the slope of your desired tangent line. If you want to, you can also solve for $y'$ in general:

$$\frac{y'}{y} + \frac1{x} = e^{x-y}-y'e^{x-y}\\
\frac{y'}{y} + y'e^{x-y} = e^{x-y} - \frac1{x}\\
y'\left(\frac{1+ye^{x-y}}{y}\right) = \frac{xe^{x-y}-1}{x}\\
y' = \frac{y}{x}\left(\frac{xe^{x-y}-1}{ye^{x-y}+1}\right)$$

Comment: Is this not too much help for the little effort that was put into the attempt?

Comment: That’s not how I think about it

Comment: Greatly appreciated. I probably would not have been able to solve it. Seems to be way beyond from the math level we are on....or maybe it's just all the variables. Either way thanks!

Comment: It’s not the easiest example of implicit differentiation, with chain rules and a product rule in there. Cheers.

Comment: If you are really only interested in $y'$ at $(1,1)$, you can make that substitution early and possibly prevent human error in solving for $y'$ in general. So from $\frac{xy'+y}{xy}=(1-y')e^{x-y}$ to $y'+1=1-y'$. Then it's quick to see the value of $y'$.

Comment: @alex.jordan, that's an excellent point, and I have edited my answer accordingly. Thanks :)